# Split the operation of constructing signed message into two parts

Tags: java, c, openssl, rsa, pkcs#1

I have a task to sign a given data with given private key and certificate and to output signed message (DER encoded). It follows the CMS standard as per RFC 3370, signature is RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5.

I can achieve this operation using `openssl` from the command line:

```
openssl cms -sign -in indata -nodetach -inkey private.key -signer public.cert -out outdata.der -outform DER
```

My problem is, that I would like to split the act of signing and the act of message construction. AFAIK for signing, we need the private key and for constructing the message we need the data from the certificate. So ideally I want to do this:

```
openssl cms -sign -step 1 -in indata -inkey private.key -out signature.bin 
openssl cms -sign -step 2 -in indata -signature signature.bin -signer public.cert -out outdata.der -outform DER
```

Is there a way to do this in any of the cryptographic libraries used in C, C++ or Java?

Comment: OpenSSL is written in C; you can use its libraries, therefore.

Comment: I have been stepping through the openssl and the way the openssl libraries are used is as such: https://pastebin.com/30xGSyHL
Looking through the CMS library API I can not see how to do it differently then CMS_add1_signer which just acceppts everything at once. I will dig deeper, but I just wanted to ask if I can do this without digging deep into libcrypto APIs